# React-Native How to show alert after an async function is complete?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-android

I have the following code which is not working to show an alert after my async function ends.

```
{
  new BaseService().request(
    serviceURL,
    "POST",
    headerParams,
    bodyParams,
    serverResponse => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true });

      AuthenticationService.completeAuthentication(
        serverResponse,
        clientResponse => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false }); // THIS WORKS AND HIDES LOADER
          alert("Authenticated Successfully!"); //THIS DOESN'T SHOW UP AN ALERT
        },
        error => {
          alert(error);
        }
      );
    }
  )
}
```

Any leads?

Comment: Maybe the BaseService request is failing? You don't seem to have an error handler function for that case, only when the AuthenticationService request fails.

Comment: No, the request gets successful. Because the loader gets hidden after that.

Comment: Alright. Have you tried using [`Alert.alert`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert) instead?

Comment: Then maybe you can share codesandbox version of this.

Otherwise, you can look at browser compatibility issues.

Comment: Yes, I tried ```Alert.alert``` as well. I'm running this on Android.
can there be anything because of background thread somewhere?

Comment: I also facing same issue, Tried showing alert and toast but no luck and response block as in question.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that not all browser functionalities will work in React Native, and that's the case for the [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) API that you are using.

If you want a similar functionality, you should try with [React Native's Alert component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert) instead

Comment: Yes, everything you said, is already tried. btw, I'm running it on Android-Pixel 9.0

Answer (score 0):

Move the alert into the callback  of `setState`

like bellow

```
clientResponse => {
  this.setState({ isLoading: false }, 
                () => alert("Authenticated Successfully!"));
},
```

Comment: Ok,  just one more suggestion. Use an Alert.aler with an OK Bytton and move the setstate statement to onClick of the OK Button..